# Order quantity and total becomes 0 in invoice magento for decimal quantity of products?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, invoice

When we click on invoice of any order,it foreced quantity and order to become 0 in case when someone ordered decimal quantity like 0.65 or 0.25 but it works fine in case of round ie 1,2,3 etc.

I checked everything including all third party extensions and i didn't edit any core file  of magento but still it is happening.

[image]

Comment: So whats the question? I can only assume you are having issues with rounding.

Comment: basically when someone ordered 0.59 quantity,it is creating subtotal,qty row total to 0 ,in another case when quantity ordered is round ie 1,2,3 than it works fine.see screenshot i attached in my question

Comment: So your issue is with rounding? Have you used `ceil()`? Ceil will round any value to the next highest number if it is a decimal.

Comment: may be but i am not sure,do you know where this exists in magento
sales_order_invoice/new

Comment: No, I've never used it. I'm trying to giving you ideas to use so you can try them and see if they work. If they do work, you should look it up in the documentation of the `magento` that does similar functionality as to what answer you have found.

Comment: i found the issue
 `if ($this->getOrderItem()->getIsQtyDecimal()) {

            $qty = (float) $qty;

        }`
is not working